# Javascript, canvas mouseover

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
function loadMain(){
      background.src = "background.png"
      button.src = "button.png"
    }

function drawMain(){
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.drawImage(button, 100, 100 , canvas.width/10, canvas.height/10);
}
```

this method does load perfectly,
my question is:
if my mouse is over that button image, how can i change to button2.png image?
thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell you can add DOM events only on elements. Here it is canvas. So if you want to have mouseover event on any of those images you would have to calculate manually if mouse is over one of them. Alternatively you could use svg if that is an option here, cos svg creates DOM tree, so you can add events to each svg element.

Comment: **Assuming:** button.png & button2.png are both fully loaded and are the same size ... **1.** Listen for mousemove events. **2.** Hit-test if the mouse is over the button: `mouseX>button.x && mouseX<button.x+button.width && mouseY>button.y && mouseY<button.y+button.height`. **3.** Clear the current button: `ctx.clearRect(button.x, button.y, button.width, button.height)`. **4.** Draw button2: `ctx.drawImage( button2, button.x, button.y, button.width, button.height)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote simple example with rectangles how to do it.

```
const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const msg = document.getElementById("msg");
const locations = [
    {x: 10, y: 10, width: 40, height: 40, title: "first", color: "red"},
    {x: 50, y: 60, width: 30, height: 30, title: "second", color: "blue"},
    {x: 30, y: 160, width: 60, height: 60, title: "third", color: "green"},
    {x: 20, y: 150, width: 40, height: 40, title: "fourth", color: "#ff40A0"}
];

locations.forEach(({x, y, width, height, color}) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
});

c.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    const {layerX, layerY} = event;

    const titles = locations
    .filter(({x, y, width, height}) => {
      return layerX >= x && layerX <= x + width 
        && layerY >= y && layerY <= y + height;
    })
    .map(({title}) => title);

    msg.innerHTML = `x: ${layerX}, y: ${layerY},
      titles: ${titles.join(', ')}`;
});
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmzr6tgo/

Basic idea is to add new event listener on 'mousemove' event in canvas element and then use layerX and layerY as mouse position in canvas. Then you only have to check if mouse is inside rectangular area, which is simple condition.